# add sound on GSAP scroll

Tags: javascript, audio, gsap, scrolltrigger

i am using GSAP scroll trigger for animating my message containers like a chatbox i want to play sound with every message appear with that also how i can do that ?
below is the code where i want to implement audio

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.5.0/gsap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.3.4/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Ensure GSAP and ScrollTrigger are loaded
  gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

  // Your GSAP animation
  gsap.from(".imageTransition", {
    y: "100%", 
    ease: "easeInOut",
    duration: 2,
    scrollTrigger: {
      trigger: ".triggerPoint",
      scroller: "body",
      start: "top top",
      end: "bottom top",
      pin :true,
    }
  });

  // Create a GSAP timeline
  var timeline = gsap.timeline();

  // Animation 1
  timeline.from(".message1", {
    x: "200px",
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "easeOut",
  });

  // Animation 2 with a stagger of 2s
  timeline.from(".message2", {
    x: "-200px",
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "easeInOut",
  }, "+=3");

  // Animation 3 with a stagger of 2s
  timeline.from(".message3", {
    x: "200px",
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "easeInOut",
  }, "+=3");

  // Animation 4 with a stagger of 2s
  timeline.from(".message4", {
    x: "-200px",
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "easeInOut",
  }, "+=3");
  
   timeline.from(".message5", {
    x: "200px",
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "easeInOut",
  }, "+=3");
  
   timeline.from(".message6", {
    x: "200px",
    opacity: 0,
    ease: "easeInOut",
  }, "+=3");


  // Use the timeline in the ScrollTrigger
  ScrollTrigger.create({
    trigger: ".triggerPoint2",
    start: "200px top",
    end: "bottom top",
    animation: timeline,
    scrub: true,
    pin: true,
    markers : true,
    onComplete: function () {
      gsap.set(".triggerPoint2", { pin: true });
    },
  });
</script>
```

i have tried using audio sound and also web api of sound on complete of every animation but it didn't work. i want to play sound everytime the message appear on scrol